# Creating buffer for only one part of feature (that borders another feature) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer

I'm using ArcGIS Pro, and I would like to create a buffer for a polygon, but only for the areas that are bordering another polygon feature.

I am trying to create a 500m buffer into an oil palm plantation bordering a forest. In the attached image, the red area is the oil palm plantation, and the green area is the forest.

Is there any way I can include the buffer for only the areas that are touching the forest?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'Buffer' tool to create a buffer feature around the forest (eg, a 100m buffer).  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm

Then use the 'Clip' tool to clip out only those parts of the plantation that overlap with the buffer.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm

If you want more or less than 100m of proximity to the forest, then change the buffer distance.